# Two Script Managers in one .aspx webform

Tags: asp.net, telerik

Using two ScriptManagers(ASP.Net and Telerik) will effect the page performance ?

I have both ASP.Net and Telerik Controls on the same page and I'm using both ASP.Net and Telerik Script managers. Can I avoid using one script manager ? How will the page performance is varried if I use two script managers  ?

and

Refering Source/SCript files in one Script manager can be used accross the other controls ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RadScriptManager replaces the ASP.NET script manager when setup correctly. You don't need both on the same page.

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/ajax/radscriptmanager-and-asp-net-s-scriptmanage.aspx

> The purpose of RadScriptManager is to
>   replace the regular asp ScriptManager
>   and allows to combine the embedded
>   script resources for RadControls for
>   ASP.NET AJAX (while at the same time
>   has the same capabilities of the MS
>   ScriptManager control).

Comment: Basically, adding both will decrease performance since script resources for both are loaded.